# How to execute commands conditionally in gdbinit functions

Tags: gdb, gdbinit

I have a `gdb` function, defined in `gdbinit` file:

```
define myfunc 
    set $retval = SOMEHOW_RET_VALUE_OF shell my-shell-command
    if $retval == 0
       load my-output
    else
       echo command not succeeded, not doing anything.\n
    end 
end
```

How can I get `my-shell-func` return status and use it to control loading new binary output?

Comment: is this useful?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572631/return-a-value-via-a-gdb-user-defined-command

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't. The key point is getting the `shell my-shell-command` output to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

The simplest way is to use gdb's built-in Python scripting capability.  For a case like the above, you could write a new convenience function that does what you like.  A convenience function is appropriate here because it can be used directly in an expression.

To write a convenience function, look through the docs for `gdb.Function`.

Then you would use it like:

```
set $retval = $_shellcommand("shell command")
```

If you'd rather not dive into Python, there is still a way; although it is somewhat more painful.

For a simple shell command, the idea would be to write the exit status of the shell command to a gdb script file, which you then source:

```
(gdb) shell false; echo "set \$retval = $?" > /tmp/q
(gdb) source /tmp/q
(gdb) print $retval
$1 = 1
```

This gets somewhat hairier if you want more than just the exit status, or if you want to use output from gdb commands in the computation.

Comment: Second "simple approach" worked quite well. Thank you.